# Two-way link, marginnote to item wanted

Tags: itemize, marginnote, hypertarget

In the following **MWE**, I am trying to link a `\marginnote` with an `\item` in the appendix. While the link does show in *red*, it is not active. If that is solved, my next step would be to create a return link such that the reader can flip back and forth in the text. This is a fragment that is enough for building and debugging. I've read what little the hypertext manual provides on `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` and can get so far as compilation without error—but as mentioned, **DOA** for all that. Everything else works and can easily be backfilled into the actual work. From other **TeX** questions, I believe that a linkage can be set automatically, but the difference in their needs and mine left me short of a working solution.

```
    % arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
    % chktex-file 1
    \documentclass[twoside,12pt,colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{book}
    \usepackage[main=latin, english]{babel}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
    \usepackage{appendix}
    \usepackage[columns=1,draft]{typogrid}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    
    \definecolor{prussianblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.19, 0.33}
    
    \newenvironment{Poem}[1]{
      % \numberedparsfalse
      \vspace{-0.25in}
      \settowidth{\versewidth}{#1}
      \begin{em}
      \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    }{
      \end{verse}
      \end{em}
      % \numberedparstrue
    }
    
    \renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
    \renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{}
    \renewcommand*{\marginnotevadjust}{3.6pt}
    \def\leftVrs{\em\hfill\footnotesize{carmen \Roman{Vrs}}\/}
    \def\rightVrs{\em\footnotesize{carmen \Roman{Vrs}}\/}
    \newcounter{Vrs}
    \setcounter{Vrs}{0}
    \newcommand{\Verse}[2]{
      \stepcounter{Vrs}
      \textcolor{prussianblue}{
        \hyperlink{Vrs}{
          \marginnote[\leftVrs]{\rightVrs}
        }
        \begin{Poem}{#1}#2\end{Poem}
      }
    }
    
    \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendice}
    \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendice}
    
    \begin{document}
    \chapter*{{\em Capvt\/} Primvm}
    aliquot carminibus
    
    \Verse{si nonnulla sint intacta,}{%
      frange uitra et catilla!\\
      \vin cultros tunde, furcas flecte!\\
      Bilbo Baggins odit illa\,---\,\\
      \vin nunc et cortices incende!\\ 
      textum seca, sebum calca!\\
      \vin lactem funde cellae terra!\\
      linque in tapeto ossa!\\
      \vin uinum sperge super porta!\\
      has patellas aestu laua;\\
      \vin has contunde magna claua;\\
      si nonnulla sint intacta,\\
      \vin uolue ea e culina!\\
      \vskip 10pt
      Bilbo Baggins odit illa!\\
      \vin caue! caue! haec catilla!
    }
    \clearpage
    \Verse{trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos}{%
      trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos\\
      altas ad latebras et ueteres specus\\
      discedamus abhinc, ante oritur dies,\\
      quaesitum in magicis auriferis locis.\\
      \vskip 5pt
      maiores faciunt carmina pristine\\
      tinnituque sonant uerbera mallei\\
      altis in spatiis quis mala dormiunt\\
      effossis domibus sub scopulis iugi.\\
      \vskip 5pt
      et reges ueteres et Dryadum duces\\
      thesauros nitidos et simul aureos\\
      fingunt et fabricant, luminaque auferunt\\
      quae gemmis tegerent in capulis ibi\\
      \vskip 5pt
      pendent florea nunc stella monilibus\\
      albis, flectitur et uertice regio\\
      anguis flammiferus, stamine ferreo\\
      nunc nocturna ligant soleque lumina.\\
      \vskip 5pt
      trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos\\
      altas ad latebras et ueteres specus\\
      discedamus abhinc, ante oritur dies,\\
      nostras immemores diuitias cape!\\
      \vskip 5pt
      caelant pocula nec non citharas sibi\\
      auri sedibus in quis habitat nemo,\\
      illic illa diu deposita atque ibi\\
      inaudita canunt carmina gentibus.\\
      \vskip 5pt
      pinetisque datis flammibus editis\\
      uentosae tenebrae cum gemitu fremunt,\\
      diffusis roseis flammibus arduis\\
      fulgentes radiant arboreae faces.\\
      \vskip 5pt
      tintinnat sonitus uallibus aereus,\\
      spectantes homines palliduli pauent,\\
      serpentis rabies acrior ignibus\\
      turres tum spoliat tum fragiles lares.\\
      \vskip 5pt
      sub luna cineres montibus excidunt,\\
      nani percipiunt exitii gradus,\\
      aulas effugiunt, exanimes cadunt\\
      eius sub pedibus, sidere sub fero.\\
      \vskip 5pt
      trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos\\
      altas ad latebras et ueteres specus\\
      discedamus abhinc, ante oritur dies,\\
      furemur citharas, aurigeros locos.
    }
    \begin{appendices}
      \chapter{carminibus}
      \section{Caput I}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item \hypertarget{1}{\emph{frange uitra et catilla} – rhythmic trochaictrans}
          \item \hypertarget{2}{\emph{Montes  Nebulae  frigore  dissitos}  –  First Asclepiad}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{appendices}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `\hyperlink` anchor should be `\theVrs`, not Vrs.  Second, while the contents of `\marginnote` appear in the margin, the macro itself is invisible (like `\hbox{}`), which makes it almost impossible to locate or click.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,colorlinks,linkcolor=red,raiselinks]{book}
\usepackage[main=latin, english]{babel}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[columns=1,draft]{typogrid}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{prussianblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.19, 0.33}

\newenvironment{Poem}[1]{
  % \numberedparsfalse
  \vspace{-0.25in}
  \settowidth{\versewidth}{#1}
  \begin{em}
  \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
}{
  \end{verse}
  \end{em}
  % \numberedparstrue
}

\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{}
\renewcommand*{\marginnotevadjust}{3.6pt}
\def\leftVrs{\hyperlink{to\theVrs}{\em\hfill\footnotesize{carmen \Roman{Vrs}}\/}}
\def\rightVrs{\hyperlink{to\theVrs}{\em\footnotesize{carmen \Roman{Vrs}}\/}}
\newcounter{Vrs}
\setcounter{Vrs}{0}
\newcommand{\Verse}[2]{
  \stepcounter{Vrs}
  \textcolor{prussianblue}{%
    \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt]{\hypertarget{from\theVrs}{\strut}}%
    \marginnote[\leftVrs]{\rightVrs}
    \begin{Poem}{#1}#2\end{Poem}
  }
}

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendice}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendice}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{{\em Capvt\/} Primvm}
aliquot carminibus

\Verse{si nonnulla sint intacta,}{%
  frange uitra et catilla!\\
  \vin cultros tunde, furcas flecte!\\
  Bilbo Baggins odit illa\,---\,\\
  \vin nunc et cortices incende!\\ 
  textum seca, sebum calca!\\
  \vin lactem funde cellae terra!\\
  linque in tapeto ossa!\\
  \vin uinum sperge super porta!\\
  has patellas aestu laua;\\
  \vin has contunde magna claua;\\
  si nonnulla sint intacta,\\
  \vin uolue ea e culina!\\
  \vskip 10pt
  Bilbo Baggins odit illa!\\
  \vin caue! caue! haec catilla!
}
\clearpage
\Verse{trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos}{%
  trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos\\
  altas ad latebras et ueteres specus\\
  discedamus abhinc, ante oritur dies,\\
  quaesitum in magicis auriferis locis.\\
  \vskip 5pt
  maiores faciunt carmina pristine\\
  tinnituque sonant uerbera mallei\\
  altis in spatiis quis mala dormiunt\\
  effossis domibus sub scopulis iugi.\\
  \vskip 5pt
  et reges ueteres et Dryadum duces\\
  thesauros nitidos et simul aureos\\
  fingunt et fabricant, luminaque auferunt\\
  quae gemmis tegerent in capulis ibi\\
  \vskip 5pt
  pendent florea nunc stella monilibus\\
  albis, flectitur et uertice regio\\
  anguis flammiferus, stamine ferreo\\
  nunc nocturna ligant soleque lumina.\\
  \vskip 5pt
  trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos\\
  altas ad latebras et ueteres specus\\
  discedamus abhinc, ante oritur dies,\\
  nostras immemores diuitias cape!\\
  \vskip 5pt
  caelant pocula nec non citharas sibi\\
  auri sedibus in quis habitat nemo,\\
  illic illa diu deposita atque ibi\\
  inaudita canunt carmina gentibus.\\
  \vskip 5pt
  pinetisque datis flammibus editis\\
  uentosae tenebrae cum gemitu fremunt,\\
  diffusis roseis flammibus arduis\\
  fulgentes radiant arboreae faces.\\
  \vskip 5pt
  tintinnat sonitus uallibus aereus,\\
  spectantes homines palliduli pauent,\\
  serpentis rabies acrior ignibus\\
  turres tum spoliat tum fragiles lares.\\
  \vskip 5pt
  sub luna cineres montibus excidunt,\\
  nani percipiunt exitii gradus,\\
  aulas effugiunt, exanimes cadunt\\
  eius sub pedibus, sidere sub fero.\\
  \vskip 5pt
  trans Montes Nebulae frigore dissitos\\
  altas ad latebras et ueteres specus\\
  discedamus abhinc, ante oritur dies,\\
  furemur citharas, aurigeros locos.
}
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{carminibus}
  \section{Caput I}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \hypertarget{to1}{\strut}\hyperlink{from1}{\emph{frange uitra et catilla} – rhythmic trochaictrans}
      \item \hypertarget{to2}{\strut}\hyperlink{from2}{\emph{Montes  Nebulae  frigore  dissitos}  –  First Asclepiad}
    \end{itemize}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Linkage back?

Comment: Note that you need different anchor names forward and back.